# same keywords two ad groups different devices

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm new to google ad words(i'm trying to advertise my father's  home business) ,so i need a little bit of help.

I have one campaign with two ad groups (lets call them ad group PC and ad group Mobile).

In ad group PC i have 20 keywords(two of those keywords are [bla] and [bla bla]) and for devices i set -100% for mobile phones,+10% for PC ,and - 100% for tablets.

In ad group Mobile i have two keywords [bla] and [bla bla] ,and for devices i set +150% for mobile phones, -100% for PC and -50% for tablets.

My question is , will that two ad groups compete with each other for the two keywords ([bla] and [bla bla]) or not? I hope not because i change device % . I did this because i don't know better way to change % for device for only one,two or three keywords.

Can this work? Will i get +150% for that two keywords on mobile phones? Ty all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ad groups will not compete since your bid for mobile phones and tablets in the PC adgroup is virtually 0,00. This also works the other way around (Mobile has a bid of 0,00 for Desktop).

I do have to say I am a bit puzzled by your bid modifiers. Why don't you just set one bid for the ad group (the value you wish to bid for mobile) and set a -..% for tablet?

Comment: Because for mobile phones i just want two keywords and for PC i want 10+ ,i did't find better way to increase % for mobile phones on specific keywords and not on whole ad group,i don't what to increase % for mobile phones on all keywords :) . Btw ty for answer.